What does inter.js do in Next.js project?
I've created Next.js project in an empty folder using npx create-next-app@latest.
I've noticed 3 .js files created at /project/src/app/ location:
inter.js
layout.js
page.js
From reading the docs, I understand the purpose of layout.js and page.js. However, it's unclear to me what inter.js does. According to Optimizing Fonts and Images, that file should be used for font imports/exports, however, it isn't used like that in my project, as it looks pretty much the same (except css import) as layout.js:
inter.js code:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
    title: "Create Next App",
    description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}

layout.js code:
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
    title: "Create Next App",
    description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </html>
    );
}


i dont think you need that file since ur layout is exactly the same here. are you sure the npx command created the inter file

@cmgchess
Yes, I'm sure... I ran npx create-next-app@latest in an empty folder...

i believe it should looks something like https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/create-next-app/templates/app-tw/js

@cmgchess
Yes, that makes more sense...

Inter is basically used for the optimization of the inter fonts from the Google Fonts. Provides a way to automatically self-host fonts and optimize their performance by eliminating external network requests.
this might be helpful:- https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts
